# iOS - Dilemna - how to segue from customized cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I have a segue from a view controller - with a enclosed tableview - to another view controller. I can segue from each cell in the first controller to the second with no problem. However, when I return to the first controller, the cell view is blank.

The dilemma is -- If I use this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

the cell is visible but segues do not work.

Does anyone know of an alternative method?

Thanks

Comment: Then don't use `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` its not meant for that, how do you perform the segue? please provide more code

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom table view cell(may be you already have one, then tweak it), lets call it `MyTableViewCell`. Then add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle tap events on cell's `contentView`. When tap occurs you can execute custom block, which you should setup for cell. In block you can perform desired segue. But enough word, lets see some code!

### First, lets define MyTableViewCell

**MyTableViewCell.h**

```
typedef void (^MyTableViewCellTapBlock) ();

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyTableViewCellTapBlock tapBlock;
@end
```

**MyTableViewCell.m**

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Tap logged");
    if (self.tapBlock) {
        self.tapBlock();
    }
}

@end
```

### Second, update your UITableViewDataSource

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    cell.tapBlock = ^ {
        [weakSelf performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:weakSelf];
    };

    return cell;
}
```

### Remarks

As you can see we have custom block that will be executed when user taps the cell. This block invokes `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, just do not forget to name your segue and change name in the sample.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the efforts Keenie.. I will hold on to that code snippet and I know I'll use it.

This is embarrassing, but it turns out that all I needed to do, was on the return from the segue, to do [[self tableView] reloadData], and all was ok..